# Enable the "redeclare" for PHP5, with .htaccess or php.ini

Tags: php

serious problem with an angry client :(

i have an issue about "Cannot redeclare variable" etc. i had a website working on PHP4 then moved to PHP5 and i have this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare CSQLAdmin::$functions in /blabla/lib/sqladmin.php on line 45
```

I tried to clear the second declaration at the file, and it fix this issue but then gives another errors. Obviously sth about php 5 is not accepting sth php 4 does...

I think i need to activate some php functions via .htaccess to make PHP5 to accept redeclaring, but how? or any setting at php.ini.

Appreciate so much!!!!!!!

Comment: Why are you re-declaring them? Are you using include/require instead of include_once/require_once? You should really fix the code instead.

Comment: it is a ready software. i didnt code it. it was working very well, btu not anymore :( i tried to fix php codes, and when I fix that re-declaring issue, it gives different errors, and looks like no end of fixing errors.... but if I can make PHP5 to accept redeclaring, it will be fine!

Comment: ps, I know they used PHP5 server a while with no problem, with same codes! and they said sth about .htaccess settings, but how!?

Comment: AFAIK you can't make PHP5 ignore fatal errors by php.ini settings. You will have to fix the code, which should not be that difficult to do.

Answer (score 2):

What value does $functions have?
Could it be that you are simply declaring $functions() twice in the same file - something PHP4 quietly accepted, if I remember correctly?

Comment: it is not about coding actually. it is working very well at PHP4. If i try to make code compatible for PHP5, it looks not possible :( many old type coding... it is opensource software. somehow I need to make PHP5 accept re-declaring.

Comment: Declaring a function twice in the same body is wrong. You can't make PHP5 accept that. YOu just need to remove the first function declaration - it is not being used anyway.